# .ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [jUnit 5 Tests]

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Good day! I ask for help in the question related to the test, I get an error :
I just started learning Junit5, so I can't understand why the error

I used various possible solutions to the problem, but unfortunately they caused even more errors :
[Junit 5 - No ParameterResolver registered for parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867650/junit-5-no-parameterresolver-registered-for-parameter)

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.service.PolicyServiceImpl policyService] in constructor [public com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.service.PolicyServiceTest(com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.service.PolicyServiceImpl)].

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:200)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:183)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:333)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

**Test class code :**

```
import com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.domain.InsuredObject;
import com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.domain.Policy;
import com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.domain.PolicyStatus;
import com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.domain.SubInsuredObject;
import com.example.InsurancePremiumCalculator.validation.InsuranceRiskType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class PolicyServiceTest {

    private final PolicyServiceImpl policyService;

public PolicyServiceTest(PolicyServiceImpl policyService) {
        this.policyService = policyService;
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldCalculatePremium() {

        SubInsuredObject subInsuredObject = new SubInsuredObject("TV", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), InsuranceRiskType.FIRE);
        InsuredObject insuredObject = new InsuredObject("House", (List<SubInsuredObject>) subInsuredObject);
        Policy policy = new Policy("ENM102938311", PolicyStatus.REGISTERED, (List<InsuredObject>) insuredObject);

        BigDecimal actual = policyService.calculatePremium(policy);
        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(24), actual);

    }
}
```

**Screenshot :**

[@Test class Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR9nv.png)

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the constructor parameter which causes the exception. You may want to initialize/set the `policyService` in a `@BeforeEach` method instead.

```
public class PolicyServiceTest {

    private final PolicyServiceImpl policyService;

    @BeforeEach
    initializeService() {
        this.policyService = new PolicyServiceImpl();
        // Do whatever kind of initialization the policy service requires
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCalculatePremium() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how to do this with an example? I need to create just a method and initialize my PolicyServiceImpl there ?