# Spring Boot Test: bean not injected

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

Here my test location:

```
src/test/java
└── cat
    └── gencat
        └── catsalut
            └── hes
                └── mpi
                    └── unit
                        └── mapper
                            └── PatientMapperTest.java
```

`PatientMapperTest.java` is:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Patient {
    
    private final TypesMapper typesMapper;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNull(this.typesMapper);
    }

}
```

I've also tried this code (deleting lombok annotation and explicitly initilize `typesMapper` field):

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class PatientMapperTest {
    
    private final TypesMapper typesMapper;

    public PatientMapperTest(TypesMapper typesMapper) {
        this.typesMapper = new TypesMapperImpl();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNull(this.typesMapper);
    }

}
```

I behaves exactly as before.

Nevertheless, when I perform `mvn test`, it seems to be ignored:

```
$ mvn test
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   PatientMapperTest.test » ParameterResolution No ParameterResolver registered f...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Related pom dependency:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This error does not mean that your bean is not injected it is something else.  Kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867650/junit-5-no-parameterresolver-registered-for-parameter

Comment: Does it work if you annotate the constructor argument with `@Autowired`?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike your production code, where you don't have to annotate your public constructor with `@Autowired`, you need it when you want constructor injection for your tests with JUnit 5.

The JUnit Jupiter `SpringExtension` (automatically registered with `@SpringBootTest`) ensures to resolve any parameter that is annotated with `@Autowired`. If you don't add `@Autowired`, JUnit doesn't know how to resolve this parameter as no one feels responsible as the Spring extension only kicks in when `@Autowired` (or another identifier) is used:

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    public class PatientMapperTest {
        
        private final TypesMapper typesMapper;
    
        @Autowired
        public PatientMapperTest(TypesMapper typesMapper) {
            this.typesMapper = typesMapper;
    
            // the original assignment doesn't make sense, why inject the instance and then manually call the constructor?
            // this.typesMapper = new TypesMapperImpl();
        }
    
        @Test
        void test() {
            assertNull(this.typesMapper);
        }
    
    }
```

As an alternative, you can also use the `@TestConstructor` annotation:

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    @TestConstructor(autowireMode = TestConstructor.AutowireMode.ALL)
    public class PatientMapperTest {
        
        private final TypesMapper typesMapper;
    
        public PatientMapperTest(TypesMapper typesMapper) {
          this.typesMapper = typesMapper;
        }
    }
```

If you want to dive deeper and understand when the `SpringExtension` resolves a parameter from the TestContext, take a look at `SpringExtension#supportsParameter`.

You can also safely use field injection for your tests:

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    public class PatientMapperTest {
         
        @Autowired
        private TypesMapper typesMapper;
    
    
        @Test
        void test() {
            assertNull(this.typesMapper);
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should register beans in test configuration file that you want to use and than inject them.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestBeans {
    @Bean
    TypesMapper typesMapper(TypesMapper typesMapper){
        return typesMapper;
    }
}
```

After registering you use them.

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestBeans.class)
public class Patient {
    @Autowired
    private TypesMapper typesMapper;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNull(this.typesMapper);
    }
}
```

or with with constructor injection.